# Binary search bit operation

Tags: binary-search

I was wondering which one of this two implementation is faster and why?

```
int N, A[N];

int binary_search(int val)
{
    int i, step;
    for (step = 1; step < N; step <<= 1)
        ;
    for (i = 0; step; step >>= 1)
        if (i + step < N && A[i + step] <= val)
           i += step;
}
```

and a normal implementation where you find `mid=(st+dr)/2` and then apply on the left side of the array or the right side depending on the value of `A[mid]` and your value?

Comment: "I was wondering which one of this two implementation is faster" – then measure it, perhaps?

Comment: Note that this is not compilable C code; you can't have a variably-modified global array and `A[N]` is variably-modified (because N is manifestly a variable).

Comment: i tried to measure it and i don't know why i get almost the same time but some people say that the first one is faster and i was wondering why?  PS:              The Paramagnetic Croissant if you don't have something good to say please hold yourself to post responds like that. You didn't help me. It is useless to post responds like that when i ask you something. I prefer to try what i know before come here and i assure you i tried what you said but i cant see very clear the difference

Comment: `for (step = 1; step < N; step <<= 1);` is exactly the same as [rounding up to nearest power of 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/466204/995714) http://stackoverflow.com/q/1322510/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/364985/995714

Comment: How does the code report that the value is missing?  Actually, how does it report where the value is found since there's no `return` in the function?  Does that code really handle all the edge cases that a normal implementation handles?

Comment: If you tried measuring and couldn't detect a difference, then (a) you should say so — we can't tell what you've tried if you don't tell us — and (b) it's possible there isn't a major benefit from the alternative implementation (and possibly not even a minor benefit).  How hard did you try measuring?  What was your test framework?  How big were the arrays you were searching?  How many iterations did you run?  Did you ensure the optimizer couldn't remove all the code?  Benchmarking is hard.

Comment: i am interested if it execute the 2 loops faster that a normal binary search. I didn't put the return and all those things after because i don't care at this moment. I want to know the speed. Pls respond with a clear answer. You want ,as i see from your comments, to annoy me with all implementation details when my goale is to find the speed not the implementation. If it find the value it exists fast else it goes until end.Did i responded to your question?

Comment: on an array of 10000 elements

Comment: No, you didn't respond to my question really.  There's no way to say a priori which of the two types of binary search is quicker — it comes down to measurement.  You said (in comments, not in the question where the information should have been) that you'd not detected a difference.  That probably means there isn't a worthwhile difference.

Comment: You have not addressed the question of how the search shown reports that the value being sought is not in the array.  AFAICT, it does it by returning the index of a value somewhere in the proximity of where the sought value would be found, so the calling code probably has to access the array to check whether the index is for the element it is interested in.  That's probably a sub-optimal design; certainly, the normal binary search outlined detects and reports that the value is not present by returning a suitable value (`-1` or `0` or `NULL`, depending on the binary search in use).

Comment: i found this solution on 'infoarena'.It is a site which prepares the romanian programmers for programming competition http://www.infoarena.ro/multe-smenuri-de-programare-in-cc-si-nu-numai  and i was wondering if that guy is right or not and if he is why because i don't see any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Conversion of pseudo-code to C code

The question asks about a code fragment which is not a working implementation of a binary search function because it does not handle the case where the sought-for value is absent from the array.

The code can be converted to a working C code function like this:

```
int binary_search(int N, const int A[N], int val)
{
    int i, step;
    for (step = 1; step < N; step <<= 1)
        ;
    for (i = 0; step; step >>= 1)
        if (i + step < N && A[i + step] <= val)
           i += step;
    if (A[i] != val)
        i = -1;
    return i;
}
```

This has been tested in a rigorous test harness and it produces the equivalent answer to other variations of binary search tested in the same harness.

#### Comparison with alternative binary search algorithms

I happen to have 4 other implementations of binary search lurking in my folder of material related to SO questions.  Given a program that can generate random numbers in a given range, and some supporting scripts, plus timing code that can report elapsed times to microseconds (it uses `gettimeofday()` on Mac OS X, much to the disgust of some, but that's good enough in this context), I generated this timing program.  It includes algorithms:

- `BinSearch_A` — find an arbitrary index P in array X[0..N-1] that matches T.
- `BinSearch_B` — find the smallest index P in array X[0..N-1] that matches T.
- `BinSearch_C` — find the largest index P in array X[0..N-1] that matches T.
- `BinSearch_D` — find both smallest (L) and largest (U) indexes in array X[0..N-1] that match T.
- `BinSearch_E` — find an arbitrary index P in array X[0..N-1] that matches T (using the algorithm in the question as amended above).

Note that algorithms B, C and D are solving strictly harder problems than A and E solve so it is to be expected that B, C, and D will be slower than A and E.

#### Outline code (`binsearch-speed-1.c`)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Pair
{
    int lo;
    int hi;
} Pair;

extern Pair BinSearch_D(int N, const int X[N], int T);
extern int BinSearch_A(int N, const int X[N], int T);
extern int BinSearch_B(int N, const int X[N], int T);
extern int BinSearch_C(int N, const int X[N], int T);
extern int BinSearch_E(int N, const int X[N], int T);

#ifndef lint

extern const char jlss_id_modbinsearch_c[];
const char jlss_id_modbinsearch_c[] = "@(#)$Id$";
#endif

int BinSearch_A(int N, const int X[N], int T)
{
    int L = 0;
    int U = N-1;
    while (1)
    {

        if (L > U)
            return -1;
        int M = (L + U) / 2;
        if (X[M] < T)
            L = M + 1;
        else if (X[M] > T)
            U = M - 1;
        else
            return M;
    }
    assert(0);
}

int BinSearch_B(int N, const int X[N], int T)
{
    int L = -1;
    int U = N;
    while (L + 1 != U)
    {

        int M = (L + U) / 2;
        if (X[M] < T)
            L = M;
        else
            U = M;
    }
    assert(L+1 == U && (L == -1 || X[L] < T) && (U >= N || X[U] >= T));
    int P = U;
    if (P >= N || X[P] != T)
        P = -1;
    return P;
}

int BinSearch_C(int N, const int X[N], int T)
{
    int L = -1;
    int U = N;
    while (L + 1 != U)
    {

        int M = (L + U) / 2;
        if (X[M] <= T)
            L = M;
        else
            U = M;
    }
    assert(L+1 == U && (L == -1 || X[L] <= T) && (U >= N || X[U] > T));
    int P = L;
    if (P < 0 || X[P] != T)
        P = -1;
    return P;
}

Pair BinSearch_D(int N, const int X[N], int T)
{
    int L_lo = -1;
    int L_hi = N;
    int U_lo = -1;
    int U_hi = N;

    while (L_lo + 1 != L_hi || U_lo + 1 != U_hi)
    {
        if (L_lo + 1 != L_hi)
        {

            int L_md = (L_lo + L_hi) / 2;
            if (X[L_md] < T)
                L_lo = L_md;
            else
                L_hi = L_md;
        }
        if (U_lo + 1 != U_hi)
        {

            int U_md = (U_lo + U_hi) / 2;
            if (X[U_md] <= T)
                U_lo = U_md;
            else
                U_hi = U_md;
        }
    }

    assert(L_lo+1 == L_hi && (L_lo == -1 || X[L_lo] < T) && (L_hi >= N || X[L_hi] >= T));
    int L = L_hi;
    if (L >= N || X[L] != T)
        L = -1;
    assert(U_lo+1 == U_hi && (U_lo == -1 || X[U_lo] <= T) && (U_hi >= N || X[U_hi] > T));
    int U = U_lo;
    if (U < 0 || X[U] != T)
        U = -1;

    return (Pair) { .lo = L, .hi = U };
}

int BinSearch_E(int N, const int X[N], int T)
{
    int i, step;
    for (step = 1; step < N; step <<= 1)
        ;
    for (i = 0; step; step >>= 1)
        if (i + step < N && X[i + step] <= T)
            i += step;
    if (X[i] != T)
        i = -1;
    return i;
}

#include "timer.h"

static const int numbers[] =
{
    10000, 10002, 10003, 10003, 10003, 10004, 10006, 10010, 10011, 10015,
    10016, 10020, 10023, 10024, 10029, 10029, 10030, 10031, 10032, 10035,
    10036, 10036, 10037, 10037, 10038, 10041, 10043, 10044, 10046, 10049,
    10066, 10066, 10069, 10070, 10071, 10074, 10079, 10080, 10085, 10086,
    10087, 10089, 10090, 10090, 10090, 10091, 10092, 10094, 10095, 10095,
```

…990 similar lines omitted…

```
    29869, 29870, 29872, 29872, 29874, 29877, 29877, 29882, 29884, 29888,
    29895, 29898, 29899, 29908, 29912, 29922, 29923, 29924, 29925, 29929,
    29934, 29936, 29938, 29939, 29941, 29942, 29943, 29943, 29944, 29945,
    29947, 29949, 29951, 29953, 29956, 29958, 29959, 29959, 29964, 29965,
    29965, 29966, 29968, 29969, 29981, 29983, 29983, 29984, 29984, 29988,
};
enum { NUM_NUMBERS = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]) };

static void check_sorted(const char *a_name, int size, const int array[size])
{
    int ok = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i-1] > array[i])
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of order: %s[%d] = %d, %s[%d] = %d\n",
                    a_name, i-1, array[i-1], a_name, i, array[i]);
            ok = 0;
        }
    }
    if (!ok)
        exit(1);
}

static int BinSearch_D1(int size, const int array[size], int value)
{
    Pair p = BinSearch_D(size, array, value);
    return p.lo;
}

typedef int (*BinSearch)(int size, const int data[size], int value);

static void time_search(const char *a_name, int size, const int array[size],
                        BinSearch function)
{
    Clock clk;
    clk_init(&clk);
    int x0 = array[0] - 1;
    int x1 = array[size-1] + 2;
    long long vsum = 0;

    clk_start(&clk);
    for (int i = x0; i < x1; i++)
    {
        int index = (*function)(size, array, i);
        vsum += (index == -1) ? index : array[index];
    }
    clk_stop(&clk);
    char buffer[32];
    printf("%s: (%d)  %lld   %s\n", a_name, size, vsum,
           clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
}

int main(void)
{
    check_sorted("numbers", NUM_NUMBERS, numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        time_search("BinSearch_A", NUM_NUMBERS, numbers, BinSearch_A);
        time_search("BinSearch_B", NUM_NUMBERS, numbers, BinSearch_B);
        time_search("BinSearch_C", NUM_NUMBERS, numbers, BinSearch_C);
        time_search("BinSearch_D", NUM_NUMBERS, numbers, BinSearch_D1);
        time_search("BinSearch_E", NUM_NUMBERS, numbers, BinSearch_E);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code works with an array of 10,000 random numbers, with repeats, in the range 10,000 to 29,999.  This means that approximately half the possible values in the range are present in the array.  For each function, it computes the index of each value in the range from the smallest number in the array - 1 to the largest number in the array + 1.  Because the algorithms legitimately return different indexes when there are multiple matches possible, the test code sums the found values (and subtracts 1 for each search failure).  The output identifies the time taken in microseconds, and prints the array size and the computed value.  One reason for the computation is to ensure the optimizer doesn't optimize too much.

I also generated a second program (`binsearch-speed-2.c`) with the same code but with 1,000,000 numbers in the range 1,000,000 to 3,000,000.  Since the times for `binsearch-speed-1.c` were in the range 0.7 - 1.4 milliseconds, the amount of data was a bit smaller than I regard as comfortable, so I increased the problem size by 100 to generate correspondingly bigger times.  However, the bigger scale problem changed the relative timings of the algorithms (which is the reason you get to see this).

The tests were run an oldish MacBook Pro (Early 2011) with 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 CPU and 16 GiB of 1333 MHz DDR3 memory, running Mac OS X 10.11.4, and using GCC 5.3.0.  Your mileage will vary!

Sample compilation command line:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -I$HOME/inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror binsearch-speed-2.c -o binsearch-speed-2 \
>     -L$HOME/lib/64 -ljl
$
```

The timing functions are in the library referenced.

#### Raw Results `binsearch-speed-1` (Size 10,000)

```
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.000817
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001076
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001006
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001337
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000787
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.000771
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001540
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001003
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001344
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000791
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.000799
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001078
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001008
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001386
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000802
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.000774
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001083
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001176
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001495
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000907
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.000817
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001080
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001007
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001357
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000786
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.000756
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001080
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001899
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001644
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000791
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.000770
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001087
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001014
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001378
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000793
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.001415
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001160
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001006
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001336
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000786
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.000763
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001079
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001012
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001309
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000796
BinSearch_A: (10000)  158341368   0.000769
BinSearch_B: (10000)  158341368   0.001094
BinSearch_C: (10000)  158341368   0.001029
BinSearch_D: (10000)  158341368   0.001397
BinSearch_E: (10000)  158341368   0.000800
```

#### Raw Results `binsearch-speed-2` (Size 1,000,000)

```
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.081161
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.137057
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.132743
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.166290
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.189696
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.083374
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.136225
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.128654
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.168078
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.190977
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.083391
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.135630
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.131179
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.168578
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.188785
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.083069
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.135803
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.136248
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.170167
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.188973
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.084509
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.145219
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.129374
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.168213
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.186770
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.086911
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.141995
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.134353
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.169639
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.194442
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.082882
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.135095
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.129635
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.166059
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.186700
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.083190
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.134491
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.130103
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.169454
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.188583
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.083038
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.135738
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.129727
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.169101
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.188749
BinSearch_A: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.082099
BinSearch_B: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.135025
BinSearch_C: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.130743
BinSearch_D: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.168684
BinSearch_E: (1000000)  1573140220897   0.188640
```

#### Statistics on raw data

```
Program             Algorithm   Tests    Avg Time     Std Dev

binsearch-speed-1   BinSearch_A    10    0.0008451    0.0002014
                    BinSearch_B    10    0.0011357    0.0001442
                    BinSearch_C    10    0.0011160    0.0002801
                    BinSearch_D    10    0.0013983    0.0001003
                    BinSearch_E    10    0.0008039    0.0000366

binsearch-speed-2   BinSearch_A    10    0.0833624    0.0015203
                    BinSearch_B    10    0.1372278    0.0035168
                    BinSearch_C    10    0.1312759    0.0024403
                    BinSearch_D    10    0.1684263    0.0013514
                    BinSearch_E    10    0.1892315    0.0022148
```

#### Provisional conclusions

When the problem size was ten thousand, then the 'shift' algorithm (`BinSearch_E`) seemed to perform a little better than the simple 'midpoint' algorithm (`BinSearch_A`), but the difference was not obviously significant — I've not run a T-Test or similar on the data.

When the problem size was one million, the 'midpoint' algorithm was better than than the 'shift' algorithm by a significant margin, and indeed it performed worse than the three more complex algorithms.

This was unexpected (especially being worse than the more complex algorithms); I expected the two algorithms to essentially the same.  I don't have a good explanation for why.  This sort of result shows why benchmarking is hard.  If I had to guess, I'd suspect that despite only need about 4 MiB of memory for the bigger array, the access pattern on the elements for the 'shift' algorithm means that the caches are less effective.  Proving (or disproving) that would be hard — it would require a better performance testing engineer than I am.

Given the consistent performance of Algorithm A (simple midpoint), which scaled essentially linearly for the tests performed, I would use that rather than Algorithm E — unless I could demonstrate that Algorithm E (shift) gave better performance on the size of data sets that the code was working with.

And this shows why benchmarking is important if the utmost in performance is important.

Comment: i am glad that you answer but you didn't resist to say again that this code doesnt work when even if i told you that my aim was not to test if the value  was or not in the vector.My aim was to see if it gets to the value faster or fi the value doesnt exist exits faster. But again thanks for your time

Comment: It's not possible to test non-working code meaningfully — so I had to have working code for the 'shift' algorithm.  And I couldn't invent the performance characteristics I saw; I was very surprised.

Comment: can you tell me how you did all of this? Where i can learn what you did so in the future i can test performance myself?

Comment: Well, the 'other 4' binary search algorithms were assembled for my answer to [SO 35147784](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35147784).  Of those, A and B were derived fairly simply from Bentley's [Programming Pearls](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Pearls-Press-Louis-Bentley/dp/0201103311/) (I used the 1st Edn rather than the 2nd Edn, which I also have).  For the SO question, I derived C as the counterpart of B. Clearly, using B & C would give the output required of D, but I combined the two into a single function instead.  _[…continued 1…]_

Comment: _[…continuation 1…]_ There is room to think that the performance of D might be better applying first B then C on the range from the entry discovered by B to the end (or, conversely, by applying C first, and then B on the range from the start to the entry discovered by C).  However, I've not yet written that code or measured it.  The timing code was originally written back in 1993 when I wanted to add timing of SQL statements to an SQL command interpreter.  I've ported it to a number of systems since then.  _[…continued 2…]_

Comment: _[…continuation 2…]_ The timing code is mainly fairy simple, except that there are variant timing system calls for subsecond times (on Unix and Windows).  Assembling a test harness that runs various functions on the same data a number of times and reports the results is more or less standard benchmarking technology.  It yields a fairly good impression of the time.  You learn that times of the order of milliseconds are not dreadfully reliable, so you want to get the times up near the 1 second range, if not larger.  The statistics is basic; I have a script to do the basics. _[…continued 3…]_

Comment: _[…continuation 3…]_ I have program to generate random numbers, and also a script to format comma-lists, and various other tools in a toolkit developed over many years.  When a problem needs to be done more than a very few times (once, nominally — sometimes it takes me longer to get around to dealing with it though), then I'll develop a script for the job.  I have over 800 scripts under version control in my bin directory, though a fairly large number are in abeyance (unused) — there are less than 600 (but more than 500) programs and scripts in my bin directory.